# Multiple file selection issue with jquery uploader (blueimp) in IE8 & IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the jquery file upload from [blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).

I have an issue in IE8 and IE9 ( I hate it :) ) with multiple file selection.

The jquery file upload framework works with HTML5.

A simple HTML code I used:

```
<form>
   <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
</form>
```

and in header I put the following javascripts:

```
<script src="jquery.fileupload.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.iframe-transport.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 10]><script src="html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Of course, in Firefox and Chrome works perfectly but not in IE8-IE9 even I put `html5shiv.js` file.

Do you know any workaround for this ? Or I have to use a framework which supports multiple environments like Flash, Silverlight ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your requests are cross-domain?

Cross-domain File Uploads using the Iframe Transport plugin require a redirect back to the origin server to retrieve the upload results.